# Точки в названии папки

Tags: java, ftp

Пытаюсь загружать файлы на ftp с помощью apache commons net, не получается создать папку с точкой в названии.

```
ftpClient.makeDirectory("/root/dir/1.0/");
```

Ошибок нет, метод возвращает false и папка не создается. Реально ли вообще создать папку с точкой в названии?

Comment: А `"/root/dir/7.8/"` работает? Может быть, такой каталог уже есть?

Comment: Именно этот не пробовал, но такого каталога нет. Без точки любой создается, с точкой никакой из тех что пробовал не работает.